# Find the interval of monotonicity for $f(x)=\frac{1}{4x^3-9x^2+6x}$

Tags: analysis, functions, derivatives, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Let $g(x)=4x^3-9x^2+6x$
$$g’(x)=6(2x-1)(x-1)$$

So $g(x)$ is strictly increasing in $(-\infty, -\frac 12)\cup (1,\infty)$ and strictly decreasing in $(\frac 12 , 1)$

So $f(x)$ is decreasing where $g(x)$ is increasing and vice versa.

But the answer says $f(x)$ is decreasing in $(0,\frac 12)\cup (1,\infty)$ instead of $(-\infty, \frac 12)\cup (1,\infty)$

I realise that $f(x)$ is discontinuous at $x=0$, but technically the function is still decreasing. What is the right answer?

Comment: You can't say that the function is monotonically decreasing in $(-\infty, \frac 12)$ because $f(\frac 14) > f(-1).$  You can say it is monotonically decreasing in the intervals $(-\infty,0), (0,\frac 12),$ and $(1,\infty)$

Comment: +1 because you recognized that the easier approach of examining $g'(x)$ rather than $f'(x)$ is valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f'(x)=-\frac{6(2x-1)(x-1)}{x^2(4x^2-9x+6)^2}.$$
I think, the right answer it's the following.

$f$ decreases on $(-\infty,0)$ on $(0,\frac{1}{2}]$ and on $[1,+\infty)$.

$f$ increases on $[\frac{1}{2},1]$.

The statement that $f$ decreases on $(0,\frac{1}{2})\cup(1,+\infty)$ is wrong.

Take $x_1=0.4$ and $x_2=1.1$.

We obtain: $x_1<x_2$ and $f(x_1)<f(x_2)$